# Flutter error getting context after updating mvc_pattern library to the last version 6.4.0

Tags: flutter, model-view-controller

before updating to the last version i am using context when calling it  inside the controller like this:

```
scaffoldKey?.currentState?.showSnackBar(SnackBar(
        content: Text(S.of(context).verify_your_internet_connection),
      ));
```

now it give me this error:

```
Undefined name of 'context'
```

this issue is confusing now ? the context cannot be gotten inside controller now after updating the mvc_pattern addons to the last version 6.4.0, how to get it? is there are any keys or something to get the context inside controller ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i opened an issue inside the plugin github account [here](https://github.com/AndriousSolutions/mvc_pattern/issues/15) and got this response:
After 6.0.0, you can get context through the getter, state.

```
BuildContext contxt = con.state.context;
```